# How will moving from Microsoft 365 to Google Workspace affect email sender reputation?

Tags: email, ip-address, marketing, reputation

As always, apologies if this somehow not the right place for this question, or it is just a bad question for the format. I've been on stack exchange for 15 years and still can't tell.

We're considering moving to Google Workspace for our productivity tools. One of our marketers, who frequently sends cold emails is concerned that his sender reputation may be negatively affected. He's worked hard to have a good reputation by being ethical and sending quality mail.

My understanding is that the following are involved, but only some of them are forces beyond his control.

- The volume of emails and consistency of sending frequency
- How many emails get deleted or instantly marked as spam by recipients
- How many times the emails get opened, replied to or just deleted.
- If many recipients quickly delete without opening, ISPs take that as a signal for unwanted email – spam
- How often the emails are marked as spam
- Sending to spam traps
- Sending to inactive email accounts
- Any complaints made to the ISP about the email sender.
- Whether the emails trigger unsubscribing from the mailing list by a lot of people
- The IP addresses used for sending

How will moving email sending from Microsoft 365 to Google Workspace affect sender reputation? I assume this mostly involves comparing the sender rep of Google Workspace and Ms 365. I'm not really sure if there are stats out there. If you know about this please share.